# Why did Ika Musume lose her squid powers?

Tags: squid-girl

At the end of season one's last episode in *Shinryaku! Ika Musume*, Ika Musume loses her squid powers, like glowing, tentacle usage, and regeneration, among others. In fact, it seems that the only power she kept was breathing underwater. Why? The anime gave no reason for her powers to go away, nor any reason for them to come back. The trigger was, "someone is in danger", but Takeru threw an inflatable orca at her to no avail, and Sanae managed to glomp Ika without being hurt. Given Ika's notorious selfishness, the best motivator should have been her being in danger, rather than someone else.

Was it ever explained or implied in the manga? Was this anime-only filler? What's the deal with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because she didn't use it as much as when she was still living on the sea her tentacle withered. So she said...

[image: Ika musume chapter 23]

Unlike the anime, the reason her tentacle grow back was because she was in danger - she saw a killer whale float

Comment: But she's always using her tentacles to do things... Still, if that's the explanation they're going for, I guess it made slightly more sense here than elsewhere. It's probably the best answer I'm going to get, at least.

Comment: well on land she use her tentacle to work and doing some stuff but on the ocean she also use it to move around, she can't swim using her limb